# Kubernetes at CNCF - contribution, CLA

Tags: kubernetes

Excuse me for this non-programming question here. Please redirect me to the right board if this is not the right place for this.
I would be interested in the conditions of contribution now that k8s becomes a hosted project in CNCF, and IP is transferred to CNCF. Can we get detailed information about the new conditions, if any? Do we have to accept other CLA than Google CLA, considering also the corporate CLA use case?
Thank you!

Comment: :)  Please elaborate where did I ask anything like this here: "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"  You know, I think, it can be pretty interesting from programming perspective how one can contribute to a project, in which project one must have accepted specific CLAs in the past, and now it may change. I have not asked for "book, tool, SW library, tutorial.." or anything like that. Also I asked for redirection to the right board. Your "put on hold" action is just funny. You do not know where to redirect me, but you put the question on hold. :)

Comment: Ahh, but you know what? Just put it on hold. Luckily I got the answers from the competent people. Interestingly, without rejection from their side.

Comment: Now we're transitioning to the Cloud Native Computing Foundation's CLA. You can visit https://identity.linuxfoundation.org/projects/cncf and sign the CLA as either an individual or an employee, whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the chair of the Technical Oversight Committee for CNCF.

We are responsible for projects & practices, operating within the CNCF charter.  The IP policy is clause 11 of the charter, and can be found here - https://cncf.io/governance  Let me know if you have questions, for example in case any of this language needs clarifying.  As Brian Grant said above, some details are still being figured out.  Overall we want to make sure every CNCF project feels that we are helping them be more successful, and this strongly influences our thinking on matters like contributions.

-- alexis

Answer (score 1):

There isn't yet an answer to your question. It is up to CNCF to decide how they are going to handle contributions once the Kubernetes IP has been fully transferred.

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed yet. As of 2 days ago, a decision had not yet been made. Once a decision is made, we'll announce it on the kubernetes-dev googlegroup.

Comment: Thank you! I started watching kubernetes-dev.